# Multiple node values to single attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. Right now I have xml which looks like this.

```
<text>
    <token>string1</token>
    <token>string2</token>
</text>
```

And I need to transform it into this format. I don't know how to take the values from multiple nodes and move them into a single attribute. This would be my desired output given the above xml.

```
<text text="string1 string2"></text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement from Ravi Thapliyal is right.
You can use `xsl:element`and `xsl:attribute`. But the "solution" (with xslt-1.0)  should more lock like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="text">
            <xsl:attribute name="text" >
                <xsl:for-each  select="text/token" >
                    <xsl:if test="position() > 1 " >
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Update: Solution using with xsl:apply-templates.

```
<xsl:template match="token" >
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1 " >
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <text>
        <xsl:attribute name="text" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text/token" />
        </xsl:attribute> 
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This works. I was confused at first where/if/how I had to use for-each.

Comment: You are right in most cases using for-each is not the best solution. Most times using `xsl:apply-templates` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<xsl:element>` and `<xsl:attribute>` tags in your XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="text">
      <xsl:attribute name="text" select="text/token" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Output***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text text="string1 string2" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I don't believe this works. the xsl:attribute tag doesn't have a select attribute. I have to use a for-each somewhere.

Comment: Did you even try this before coming to the conclusion that it doesn't work? Do you mean I've put the word `Output` there for fun?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I also think this would not work with an xslt-1.0 processor. (It does not with xlstproc!) Do you use xslt-2.0? Hm but your  xsl:stylesheet  is 1.0.

Comment: @hr_117 Yes, I usually use Xslt 2.0 but this stylesheet was written online. Try it [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html). **It works.** The header was copied from the sample below which had it's version set to 1.0 but a 2.0 transformer would parse it happily. And, why would I claim that something works and post the output if it wasn't working? This was pretty distasteful especially coming from someone who clearly can't get this working on his own. Simply ridiculous!

Comment: I appreciate that you gave a solution to my problem, and obviously I am new to xslt, but when I tried it with the xslt processor i am using, it did not work. There was no need for the hostility in your tone, which is why I was reluctant to respond to you again.